# Error in displaying background image of my windows application after deploying

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, windows, servicepacks

I am building a windows application in Visual studio 2010 using C  Sharp.
The problem is not with any code.
I am having a problem after deployment. When i made an executable .exe of the application it will work fine with operating systems like Windows 7, Window Vista etc. but it won't display any background image when i install the application which is having operating system Windows Xp with Service Pack 2 or 3.

Can anyone please give me a workable solution!

Comment: Although you can exicute the .exe file in Windows XP, it may not be processed correctly. Try this on the XP machine:
1. Right-click the .exe file and choose Properties.
2. On the General tab, click the button labeled "Unblock".
3. Click OK.

Comment: I am not having any problem in running the exe in my windows xp system. The application will install in my system. The problem is what all backgrounds and images that i have aplied to my project will not be shown!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I thought it was a background image on the installer itself. Is this beta .exe software application available to test?

Comment: Run Windows Event Viewer via `eventvwr.msc` in the Run Box and look for any Application/System message logs related to the install of your application on a Windows XP SP3 machine. Report anything related to your install here in your Question. Tip: Ensure your app is not installed (or remove first), Clear Application/System Event Logs, and then reinstall application to have fresh/clear log files in Event Viewer.

Answer (score 1):

The installation of [**The Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) on your **Windows XP3** machine is required since your application was made with **Visual Studio 2010**.

If the **Windows XP** Machine is at **SP2**, it will need to be upgraded to **SP3** first.

Reference used for this answer: [**Visual Studio 2010 application on Windows XP**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/abea2416-b7cc-4e48-9135-9795f1ea6264)

Let's set aside what I just wrote since you mention that the application is running in your Windows XP System but without backgrounds or images. Are these assets suppose to be tangible objects in the programs application directory? If so, scan the whole hard drive to see if these images are somehow installed in a different path.

Another tip, try this first, is to install your **.exe** on a ***different*** Windows 7 or Vista machine. If this different Windows machine also shows the same missing backgrounds and images, it will then be evident that the **.exe** was not properly created and is using project assests instead of installed application assets on the machine that works.

Comment: There is no problem with Windows 7/Vista Installation. Background images are working fine. But when i tried to install it in Windows Xp background images are not displaying.

Comment: @Joms, do you have test .exe file that is available for analysis?